# OAuth and DocuSign connect

Tags: oauth, docusignapi, webhooks

After completing the DocuSign's OAuth flow with my Docusign App I would like to add a webhook to the user's account using the [Connect APIs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectConfigurations/create/).

What I managed to achieve so far is complete the OAuth flow, get the token and create a webhook on my OAuth app but instead I want to create it on the user's one.

I think it should be possibile since it's exactly what the [DocuSign API explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Connect&tags=ConnectConfigurations&operations=create) is doing: it first makes me follow the OAuth and then allows me to create a webhook on my account.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your OAuth identity on DocuSign can be associated with one or more accounts. You create an account-wide webhook by specifying the account_id in the [ConnectConfigurations: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectConfigurations/create/) call to end point POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/connect

So some choices:

1. If your login has access to your user's account then you're all set.
2. When your user logs in to DocuSign you could create the webhook using his credentials.

You can also use Service Application authentication, but in all cases, the login used by your app needs permission for the user's account to add a webhook on that account.

**Note:** by "user" I am assuming that you mean someone who is sending out envelopes. We call that person the "sender." People who receive or sign envelopes typically don't have accounts. They're "recipients."

If you want to know when someone signed, you should add a webhook on either the sender's account or on the envelope itself when it was sent.

Comment: Yes by "user" I mean the sender of the documents to be signed.
I'm interested in receving webhooks of signs of all envelopes sent by that sender.

What's not clear yet is : should I create webhooks on my OAuth application using the accountId of the user who completed OAuth?

Comment: @user3933324 -- yes. A webhook for a sender's envelopes is created on the sender's account. Or include an eventNotification object with every envelope creation request.

Comment: So that user doesn’t need to create its own OAuth client app right? By using mine I will be able to register webhooks on its behalf on its account, is that correct?